# Standard notation for the complete graph with self-loops?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

$K_n$ is the standard notation for the complete simple (undirected) graph of $n$ vertices, where every vertex is connected to every *other*. Is there a(n even vaguely) standard notation for the "really" complete (undirected multi)graph of $n$ vertices, where every vertex is connected to every other *and to itself* - for a total of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ edges, rather than $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$?

Comment: I'm not sure there exists "standard notation" for such a thing is as I have never seen it. You could just write the complete graph with self-loops on $n$ vertices as $\bar{K}_n$.  In any event if there is any doubt whether or not something is standard notation or not, define explicitly. I'd even specify $K_n$ explicitly as the complete graph on $n$ vertices to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: @Mike I agree wholeheartedly with you about the rule "when in doubt, define it explicitly". But the issue is, if there *is* even vaguely-standard notation for something, it's much better (in terms of ease for the reader) to use *that* regardless. For example it's much better to use $K_n$ for the complete graph on $n$ vertices rather than, say $\Gamma(n)$, even if you define it explicitly. Hence the question.

Comment: to answer the question of whether there is even "vaguely standard" notation, I have read many papers on graph theory and I have seen no such thing (sorry). So I am going to go with no.

Comment: @Mike that's a decent answer (you could post it as an actual answer, in fact, so others can upvote it to confirm they agree)! And nothing to be sorry about. If there's is no standard, or even vaguely standard notation (and your having read many papers on graph theory without finding it is some guarantee) than I know that I am free to define it as I wish, possibly in some way vaguely reminscent of $K_n$, without generating confusion in the reader!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find anything in Diestel or Bollobas. I don't think there are any "standard" notations. Maybe you could use $\mathring{K_n}$, with $\LaTeX$ as`\mathring{K_n}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in with Mike, standard notation is rare in graph theory. People can't even agree if "graph" without additional information refers to "simple graph" (no loops and multiple edges between the same vertices) or "multi graph" (possibly multiple edges between the same vertices; loops or not is again not standard, some call the construct without loops "multi graph", some call it "pseudo graph"), just that it does not mean "digraph" (at most one edge per direction between the same vertices).

The complete graph $K_n$, the cycle graph $C_n$ and the path graph $P_n$ (with $n$ vertices respectively) are more common, but I would always refer once what I mean by these symbols (like I just did), just to be sure. The only case when I would safely omit explanations is when I'm in a lecture and my professor defined exactly what he means by which notation, if I would have to give in exercises I would use his definitions without explanation.

Given your problem, I know of no such notation. Similar to Larry's suggestion, I would define an operation for any graph $G$ to denote the graph resulting from adding loops to any vertex of $G$ and combine this with $K_n$ then.

Since simple graphs can be interpreted as relations ans vice versa, you may want to look up a book about relations, because you are effectively making your relation reflexive with this operation. Maybe there already is a symbol for reflexive closure of relations, I don't know.